# Is there a software for drawing cause-effect graphs?

Tags: drawing

Is there a software for drawing cause-effect graphs? I would like to be able to draw something like this:

[image]

I've been searching around and haven't been able to find anything that does exactly what I want yet.

[SmartDraw](https://www.smartdraw.com/cause-and-effect/examples/) claims to allow this, but its cause-effect templates are not like the one above at all.

I know I can probably do that manually by inserting a "^" and "v" next to the edges for "and" and "or" relationships, and drawing 2 half-circles in the edges for "not" relationships, but it would be a lot easier if there was a software that automatically did that for me.

Comment: You want paid or free?

Comment: Any, I just cannot find any software that does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

There may be software that is designed fo this http://benderrbt.com/bendersoftware.htm#rbt

however, LibreOffice Draw will likely do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) suite. You might have edges with labels containing appropriate symbols (probably some weird Unicode characters).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Tikz (a LaTeX library for drawing graphs), see, e.g., [this answer on StackOverflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277371/64293).